# Compress video file before uploading it to server in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

Actually, I am developing a simple chatting application with angular 6 and PHP CodeIgniter, where users can upload videos. The problem is: If the user records a video with a phone, then a 1 minute video at 1080p may take approx. 150MB in size. And uploading 150MB through mobile is very difficult. So I want to compress the video before uploading it to the server so users will be able to easily upload a video.

Comment: please, help me to solve this problem...